# how to connect asp.net web application with outlook?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I have created a we application for managing the contacts. I want to save the selected contact to current user's outlook contact list. how to do this? I am using asp.net + c#.net. please guide me.

**Edited** :

I have done this by following this link.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rambab/outlookintegration10282006032802am/outlookintegration.aspx?login=true&user=lalitcdhake

its a great and easy to understand windows application for the same. I used Class library. It is running fine locally. but s I deploy my application in IIS and access it from outside network it showing dialog box with message :

" an unhandled win32 exception occurred in outlook.exe [876] "

What should be that ? can somebody guide me for this please?

**Edit 2:**

Problem is still there. While i debugging the application I am getting the exception:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005. + OUTLOOK

I found this is the User Account Control problem on some blog. Is it true? Or What should be the solution over this. Is any another way rather than Interop services?

Comment: the Office automation APIs are meant for automating the Office applications. These are _desktop_ applications. The cannot be used in a server environment. They are not designed to do so, and they **will not work**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should offer the contact as a vCard. When the user clicks on the "download" link, they will be prompted to add the vCard as a contact in Outlook.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard

Besides avoiding Office COM Automation, which is totally incompatible with ASP.NET, vCards are nice because everyone supports it.

Comment: +1 for avoiding Office Automation... I've been burned too many times in the past

Comment: Ok, fine but how to use vCard in my asp.net application for my requirements . what should be the steps for this?

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan Allen.its a nice article. it is about only generate vCard ,but how to save this vCard in the outlook programmatic way? please guide .waiting here dude.

Comment: any updates please. I got how to generate the vCard through the c# . but cn u please tell me how to save it in outlook through c# ??

Comment: There is none. Users just click on the link and they are prompted to add the Contact.

Comment: No,Jonathan Allen . I tried your link 
codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/vCardExport.aspx
It is running fine. but it not askin me to save it in the outlook contacts. please tell me have you done this before (save vcard in outlook programatically) ??

Comment: You should just return the vCard to the user's browser with the correct content type. You may or may not need to send it as an attachment. Since Outlook is registered for that content type, it will open the contact.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the Automation API of any Office product from a web application. It doesn't work; it may violate the terms of  your license. The automation APIs and the applications themselves are not tested in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: But what technique have to use then ?? please guide........ As observe my updated question. I mentioned, it is working locally. but after deployed it is giving error.

Comment: @Lalit: STOP USING THAT! This is exactly the kind of random behavior that occurs. Outlook is a desktop application. It is not designed to work in a multithreaded server environment. DO NOT USE IT THIS WAY.

Comment: Yes, john I agree with you. but what should the other way to do this? I want to save my selected contact information to the outlook of client who is currently accessing the application. what have to do. please suggest other way then.

Comment: @Lalit: See Jonathan's answer below.

Comment: Hi john, I tried that dude. but wondering about there is no such option to save that vCard in outlook. how can i do this. still in trouble...

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the contacts as CVS file format
2. Import the CVS to outlook.

[How to Import a Comma Separated Value (CSV) File Into Outlook](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/calendar/sync/sync-11.html)

Comment: @Downvoter: please be an adult and tell everyone what's wrong with my answer.

Comment: It isn't reasonable to ask a user to download a CSV file and run the import/export utility to load a single contact.

Comment: The question was "Managing  Contacts", and selected contact could be more than one, in addition CVS could work for a single or multiple Contacts.

Comment: Personally I use Com solution in winform application because each user should have his own license, but you cannot do it in the server-side without license agreement.  See the link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: ok, thanks Waleed. I will not use the interop at server side for this requiremnt. But I have problem what should then the steps contain to prepare the CSV fiel from C#. and how to save it to accessing clients outlook contacts information. Please guide.

Comment: My suggestion is to use another program that is schedule to run every period of time to access the contact database “Now you can use the Com interrupt” and import them directly to outlook. In addition add a flag for imported contacted and flag for the contact that you want to import.

Comment: see, can i use interop in the class library project? since it will be on the server. only the aspx will use it on the fly. can this possible Waleed ?

Comment: :) My suggestion say "another program" on the server or any machine  run locally. and not aspx.

Comment: @Lalit: Don't forget [@John Saunders] answer about the "multithreaded environment"

Comment: ok, Waleed I agree. so you mean to say I have to write the windows service, that will fetch the contact information of configured outlook from contact database from the pop3 email server. and as I say "Add to Outlook" from my another web application, this will happens. and then it will add new contact to downloaded contact data. and will be uploads through the same windows service. Is I am right about catching you? Or is this possible, dude ?